# How to specify the SearchVector content manually in Django for Postgres?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Django supports the Postgres full-text-search using a `SearchVectorField`. The data has to be prepared using `to_tsvector` on the Postgres side which is done by the `SearchVector` function in Django:

```
class SomeSearchableModel(PostgresModel):
    searchable = SearchVectorField()
```

I need to populate this column with data not stored in other columns of the table. The default way to go would be:

```
class SomeSearchableModel(PostgresModel):
    text = TextField()
    searchable = SearchVectorField()
```

On every save:

```
    obj.searchable=SearchVector('text') # Column name to be read
```

This application doesn't hold the searchable data in a usable format within the database. The content is prepared within some backend script.

**How do I provide the `SearchVectorField` content manually?**

Like:

```
    obj.searchable=SearchVector(some_processed_text)
```

The PostgreSQL query part would be: `INSERT INTO ... SET searchable=to_tsvector(...)`.

Calculating the content in Postgres is no option.

Answer (score 1):

The arguments to SearchVector can be any Expression or the name of a field. Multiple arguments will be concatenated together using a space so that the search document includes them all.
￼￼
`SearchVector(Value('some text'))`

Thanks to Swen for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just use the search look up.

Taken from - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/postgres/search/#the-search-lookup

```
Entry.objects.filter(body_text__search='Cheese')
```

Comment: No, thank you. This does a full-table-scan converting the column (here: `body_text`) to a SearchVector on the fly and throwing everything away after the query. Not suitable for a million of rows (or more).